# How to select first element in every page in pagination like $event click in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have created a pagination example dynamically in angular. Now ng-click event works fine with ng-repeat. when I click on any row element I styled it dynamically using ng-style(with red border). After that if I click on collapse button the selected row collapses. Now I want this selection to inherit to every first row element with border red without clicking it by default on pageload. just by directly clicking on collapse button, the first row should collapse just like how ng-click is working for every row. when I click on prev, next buttons in both gold and silver links how can I make this work only for every first element selected with red border & be also able to work with collapse button to it. do I have to use data-ng-init="";? Any help would be grateful. I have my plunkr link demo below including json file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
body{background:#fff;height:100%}h2{text-transform:capitalize;font-size:14px;color:#636363;font-weight:700}.small{width:100%;text-align:left;float:left;background:#efefef;line-height:50px;border-bottom:1px solid #bfbfbf}#btns{float:right;z-index:0;position:relative}#gold,#hide,#leftBtn,#rightBtn,#silver{width:auto;min-width:48px;height:48px;border:none;outline:0;float:left;border-radius:7px;margin:10px 10px 10px 0}#hide{margin:10px 0}#rightBtn{float:right}#gold,#silver{background:pink}.link{color:#2196F3;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default;opacity:.4}div.caption{font-family:Oswald,sans-serif;color:#000;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:15px;margin:0;float:left}

</style>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="tabCtrl">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="main">


      <div class="row">
        <button id="gold" class="active" ng-click="gold()">gold</button>
        <button id="silver" class="" ng-click="silver()">silver</button>

        <button id="hide" ng-click="hide()" class="pull-right"> collapse </button>


        <div class="small" ng-repeat="x in myData | startFrom:(currentPage)*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" ng-click="setActive(x, $event)" ng-style="activeMenu === x && divStyle">

          <h2 class="col-md-4 pull-left">  {{ x.caption }} </h2>

          <div class="col-md-4 pull-left"> {{ x.description }} </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 link text-right">view site</div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <!--previous, next buttons-->

      <div id="btns">
        <button id="rightBtn" ng-disabled="currentPage >= myData.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1;">next</button>
        <button id="leftBtn" ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">prev</button>

      </div>

  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('tabCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 5;
    $scope.myData = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myData; i++) {
        $scope.myData.push(i);
    }

    $scope.numberOfPages = function () {
        return Math.ceil($scope.myData.length / $scope.pageSize);
    }

    var x, y;

    $http.get("category.json").then(function (response) {

        $scope.myData = response.data.gold;
        $scope.gold = function () {
            $scope.currentPage = 0;
            $scope.myData = response.data.gold;
        }
        $scope.silver = function () {
            $scope.currentPage = 0;
            $scope.myData = response.data.silver;
        }

        $scope.setActive = function (list, $event) {
            $scope.activeMenu = list;
            y = '';
            y = angular.element($event.target).prop('clientHeight');

            $scope.divStyle = {
                "border": '2px solid red',
                "pointer-events": "none"
            }

        }

        $scope.hide = function () {
            $scope.divStyle = {
                "height": y * 2 + 'px',
                "border": '2px solid green',
                "pointer-events": "none"
            }
        }

    });
});

app.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        /*if (!angular.isArray(input)) { return []; }*/
        if (!input || !input.length) {
            return;
        }
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    };
});

</script>
```

[PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/eKgA5xdhY8DCxWsRjtsR?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this should be your solution, I think I have understood your requirements, please go through and let me know if you have any issues with the code.

<kbd>**Plunkr Demo**</kbd>

I am using the condition `$index === 0`, but I am also adding another condition where if there is any selection, the first row will get disabled. This gets reset when you press the buttons `gold` and `silver`

There was another issue in your code, you had declared the style object inside the `$scope.setActive` function, I have moved it out, only then the style will get applied by default.

Apart from this, this is how I implemented the functionality!

```
        <div class="small" ng-repeat="x in myData | startFrom:(currentPage)*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" ng-click="setActive(x, $event)" 
          ng-style="$index === 0 && testBool ? divStyle : activeMenu === x ? divStyle: ''">

          <h2 class="col-md-4 pull-left">  {{ x.caption }} </h2>

          <div class="col-md-4 pull-left"> {{ x.description }} </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 link text-right">view site</div>

        </div>
```

This `testBool` scope variable is intially set to true. Then when any of the elements is clicked its set to false using the function.

```
        $scope.setActive = function (list, $event) {
          $scope.testBool = false;
            $scope.activeMenu = list;
            y = '';
            y = angular.element($event.target).prop('clientHeight');
        }
```

Then finally when the user presses the `gold` or the `silver` button, the variable is reset to `true` so that the first element will be selected again.

```
  <button id="gold" class="active" ng-click="gold();testBool = true;">gold</button>
  <button id="silver" class="" ng-click="silver();testBool = true;">silver</button>
```

I hope my explanation was understandable, please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: I can see first element gets selected for every page, but if i click on second element and click next and come back by clicking prev, i can see first element and second element both got selected. I want only first elements to be selected by clicking prev, next. Also if i click collapse button, and click prev, next its getting collapsed for all first elements. it should not collapse until I click on collapse button. that's the reason i declared style object inside $scope.Active. please help

Comment: @jake ok is this the functionality that's needed? [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DIamCmKBSdsjmO19lBc0?p=preview)

Comment: yes, finally one more thing. but did you observe, once if its collapsed, then if I click on any item its collapsing by default. It shouldn't collapse until I click on collapse. if i click collapse button, and click prev, next also any item its getting collapsed by default.

Comment: @jake check this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DIamCmKBSdsjmO19lBc0?p=preview), please take care of the rest yourself

Comment: Works Great! Thanks a lot. I appreciate for your valuable time.You made my day. I gave a tick :)

Answer (score 0):

To select by default 1st element you can write something like:

```
  ng-style="$index === 0 ? divStyle : ''"
```

---

You can also make your code simple by put out and write something like:

```
<div id="btns">
        <button id="rightBtn" ng-disabled="currentPage >= myData.length/pageSize - 1" 
        ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1;activeMenu=myData[currentPage*5];">next</button>
        <button id="leftBtn" ng-disabled="currentPage == 0"
        ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1;activeMenu=myData[currentPage*5];">prev</button>

      </div>
```

[Demo PLunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yd3eJs1NB3exDNzspC2b?p=preview)

Comment: please click on silver button and click next, and now click on gold and silver alternatively without clicking prev, next buttons its not working for first pages for two of them

Comment: cool, sorry i forgot one more thing, if I click on any item and click collapse button its collapsing. but its collapsing for all first items when i click prev, next.  but It shouldn't collapse until I click on collapse. also please update with with ng-click on all items. right now its working only for first elements.

Comment: @jake well, I think you can sort things out as homework :) . I gave you direction

Comment: :) I'm new to angular and in very basics. I will try my best anyway. You can take your time if you want to. I was trying for this from weeks and couldn't get it .  :(

Answer (score 0):

```
  You can use $first property with ng-class in ng-repeat like 

 <div class="small" ng-class="$first?'active':''" ng-repeat="x in myData | startFrom:(currentPage)*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" ng-click="setActive(x, $event)" ng-style="activeMenu === x && divStyle">
```

Comment: can you help me with plunkr demo